# Angular 1.5.x - Directive not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm practicing working with directives, and have been banging my head on this for a while now.

The code -

### Module

```
angular.module('wbHeader', []);
```

### Controller

```
angular.module('wbHeader').controller('wbHeaderController', ['$scope', function() {

}]);
```

### Directive

```
angular.module('wbHeader').directive('wbHeader', function() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'AEC',
    scope: {

    },
    controller: 'wbHeaderController',
    templateUrl: '/modules/wb-header/header.html'
  };
});
```

#### Plunker -

https://plnkr.co/edit/OUrCm1mGb5K0wN8u2Ke9?p=preview

I feel like I'm overlooking something simply, but not sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes simple,In your code ng-app should be renamed as

Change

**From**

```
<html ng-app="wbApp">
```

**To**

```
<html ng-app="wbHeader">
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/YvCMZZjlON2b8qazb2QR?p=preview)**

Comment: Not exactly what I did, but gave me a hint, updated the plunker with what I actually wanted - https://plnkr.co/edit/YvCMZZjlON2b8qazb2QR

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace `wbHeader` with `wbApp` in controller,directive,and modulejs like here `angular.module('wbApp').directive('wbHeader'` in directive